# Find the count of the solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How many are the solutions of the equation $$1 - \frac{x^2}{2} = cosx$$
I've found one solution to be $x = 0$ because it was just obvious, but I genuinely don't know how to proceed with equations where the variable is an algebric and trigonometric argument at the same time. Does one usually just assume that the value for $x$ is taken in degrees when it's an argument of $cos$ or how do we even approach such problems? Thank you!

Comment: Take $x$ to be in radians. Plot $y = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}$ and $y=cos(x)$ on the same graph and have a think.

Comment: That makes perfect sense this way! So does one by rule always take $x$ to be in radians or is it somehow dependable on something? With what you said it's obvious that the solution is only $x = 0$.

Comment: The key to this conclusion being the fact that $\frac{\pi}{2} > \sqrt{2}$

Comment: In general always use radians unless told otherwise. Typically, degrees would only appear in geometry problems.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your hint!

Answer (score 3):

Correct me if wrong:

$f(x):=x^2/2 + \cos x - 1.$

1) $x >0:$

$f'(x)= x - \sin x>0.$

Strictly increasing for $x >0.$

2) $x<0:$

$f'(x) = -((-x) - \sin (-x) ) < 0.$
(Note $-x >0$, case 1))

Strictly decreasing.

Hence only one zero at $x=0.$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

Compare the derivatives on $\; \bigl[0,\frac\pi2\bigr]$ and use this corollary of the *Mean value theorem*:

> Let$f,g$ two continuous functions on $[a,b]$, differentiable on $(a,b)$. If  $fa\le g(a)$ and $f'(x)<g'(x)$ for all $x\in(a,b)$, then
>   $$f(x)<g(x)\enspace\forall x \in (a,b].$$

Answer (score 0):

By taylor formula (http://www.stewartcalculus.com/data/CALCULUS%20Early%20Transcendentals/upfiles/Formulas4RemainderTaylorSeries5ET.pdf),

$$
\cos(x) = 1 - x^2/2 + \int_0^x \sin(u)\frac{(x-u)^2}{2!}\,du
$$ Note that $(x-u)^2$ is largest at $u=0$ and that for the positive direction, $\sin(u)$ starts off with a possitive cycle so the integral should be positive for all but $x > 0$ the case $x<0$ follows similarly.